# Why pouring sanitizer on hand feel much cooler than water although both perform evaporation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, evaporation

Which absorb more heat from hand?

Sanitizer or Water?

Both absorb heat from hand than why pouring sanitizer on hand make hand feel much cooler than rhat of water?

Comment: You might find this article about alcohol vs water for evaporative cooling helpful https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/chilling-science-evaporative-cooling-with-liquids/

Comment: I have watch it, good one

Comment: This can get tricky when dealing with non-evaporative conditions.  In such cases, things feel "hotter" or "colder"  based on the rate of heat transfer between your skin and the substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most sanitizers contain alcohol. The alcohol evaporates faster than water at room temperature. So it absorbs heat at a faster rate than water. You can compare the sensation with those sticky sanitizers used by some stores, that contain no alcohol and leave your hand greasy/sticky. These do not feel cool to me. And by "cool"  I mean both temeraturewise and rearding the sensation you feel when you, unknowingly, use them.

Edit - to add more detail
When your hand is in contact with a liquid which is colder than the body temperature there are two things that happen:

1. Heat is transfered from the warmer body to the colder one. Water has a larger specific heat so it can absorb more heat than other liquids, for the same change in temperature.
2. The liquid evaporates and this decreases the temperature of the liquid. The relevant quantity here is the latent heat of evaporation but also the vapor pressure which tells you how fast the fluid will evaporate.

So, when you compare water with alcohol both specific heat and latent heat are larger for water than for alcohol. But the alcohol evaporates faster.
And what you have is a thin layer of alcohol in contact with your hand. The main effects is the heat lost by evaporation of the alcohol. The fact that the alcohol has lower specific heat capacity is another "plus" as it heats up faster from the hand and this contribute to increase evaporation rate.

But if you dip your hand in a specific amount of alcohol or water closed in an insulated container so that neither one evaporates in the process and they don't loose heat to the environment, you will have to transfer more heat to the water than to the alcohol to reach the equilibrium. But this is not what gives the sensation of heat or cold. The sensation does not depend on how much heat I am going to loose in the next hour but on the rate of heat transfer right now. At least it looks like this, approximately. The sensation is not linear in the rate of heat transfer, I suppose.

Comment: So why my hand feel much cooler by sanitizer than water?, water also evaporate

Comment: Yes, they both eaporate but the alcohol evaporates faster.  Loosing heat faster translates into a sensation of "colder". Similar reason for a metal feeling colder than an insulator. They both transport heat away from you hand but the metal does it at a faster rate. The sensation of cold is related to how much and how fast the body looses heat.

Comment: @AnshikaSingh It's kind of like an engine. You get more power out of nitromethane than gasoline even though gas has more energy per volume because you can burn nitromethane much. much faster.

Comment: Ok thank u so much

Comment: @Nasu i have to ask if we take same amout of water and alcohol on hand, overall water will lower the temp much than alcohol(high evaporation temp needed)but alcohol lower the temp at much faster rate, so in sudden lowering it feel cool ratger than slow gradual lowering of temp by water. So feeling it and actually what is happening is different, right??

Comment: Re, "sticky sanitizers used by some stores"; Some people don't know the difference between "hand sanitizer" and "anti-bacterial hand soap." I have been surprised on more than one occasion to get a dose of soap or detergent from a public dispenser that was labelled "hand sanitizer," and no water near by to wash it off with. Eeech! I carry my own now if I think I'm going anywhere I might want it.

Comment: There is also "hand sanitizer" which has no alcohol. Possibly to protect the skin from de-hidration or other type of degradation.

Answer (score 0):

> Which absorb more heat from hand? Sanitizer or Water?

By "sanitizer" I'm assuming you mean an alcohol based product with minimum 60% alcohol as recommended by the FDA.

Given the same mass of water and alcohol, and allowing both to completely evaporate, the water will absorb more heat since it has a greater heat capacity than alcohol (2260 J/g vs 879 J/g). Exactly how much more would depend on the non alcohol components of the sanitizer.  But alcohol will absorb heat more quickly because it has a lower boiling point (82 C compared to 100 C for water at 1 atm).

Given the above, while the alcohol in the sanitizer will make the skin feel cooler than water, even if the sanitizer was all alcohol  it would completely evaporate before the same amount of water ending the cooling effect of the alcohol. The cooling effect of the water will continue until it completely evaporates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So.... If we take same amount of water and alcohol, although a cooler sensation will feel with alcohol because faster rate of heat tranfer, but i think water will cool down the temperature much after full evaporation (overall, not sensation ) because it has high heat absorbing capacity that alcohol as u said, so same amount of water will cool diwn hand at a much lower temp. Than alcohol after complete evaporation, if we measure Temp in both cases, Right or not?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. While the  same amount of alcohol and water are in contact with the skin, the skin temperature will be lower for the alcohol. But after the alcohol completely evaporates (which will occur before an equal mass of water), the bare skin temperature will rise and be greater than the temperature of the skin in contact with the remaining water.

Comment: No no, I think u dont get me , i m saying suppose i take same amt. Of alcohol and water in 2 DIFFERENT hands, after the compkete evaporation of alcohol we immediately measure temp. Let say x° and after complete evaporation of same amount of water on other hand, immediately measure temperature let say y°, so according to me y°<x°, because same amt of water has to absorb more heat evaporate than same amt. Of alcohol, but due to faster rate of evaporation in alcohol at that particular time alcohol absorb more heat than water at some POINT of time(not comp. Evaporation) which give us a sudden cool

Comment: For the first part of what you said, if by "immediately" after evaporation you mean you are able to measure the temperature of the skin before it begins to change, then yes, that temperature will be lower for alcohol than water because it was lower while the fluids were present. For the last part, the alcohol absorbs more heat only because more of it evaporates at a given time. But the heat absorbed per unit mass of alcohol evaporated is lower than the heat absorbed per unit mass of water evaporated because water has a higher heat of vaporization.

Comment: Yah i got it, thanks